# Show specific div based on variable in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show or hide specific divs based on if `&Internal=True` or `&Internal=False` how would I go about that?

Here is the URL: http://www.url.com/sub/page-name/?code=1234-1234-1234-1234&Internal=True

Something like?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('&Internal=True')) {
        $( "#internal" ).show();
        $( "#external" ).hide();
    } else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('&Internal=False')) {
        $( "#internal" ).hide();
        $( "#external" ).show();        
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I want to show or hide specific divs based on if &Internal=True or &Internal=False

Comment: And the code snippet you have isn't doing it?

Comment: Why don't you use PHP to set a JS variable... ? Or use PHP to hide/show the div... ?

Comment: @Loenix - That's too convoluted and makes assumptions that the OP is using PHP in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick, the `$` var had a conflict:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('&Internal=True')) {
        $( "#internal" ).show();
        $( "#external" ).hide();
    } else if ( document.location.href.indexOf('&Internal=False')) {
        $( "#internal" ).hide();
        $( "#external" ).show();        
    }
});
</script>
```